# Serious problem with chat

Tags: bug, chat, design

I opened a gallery room to look at it, and this is what the request access banner looks like:

[image: Chat room banner]

I don't think that's supposed to happen. You have to select the text just to see it.

Comment: @Henry There's supposed to be text saying: "Only users nominated may talk here". That text is there but you can't see it because of the colors.

Comment: I know. Doesn't this need to be fixed?

Comment: This is a styling bug and evidently the style is not the one associated with this site. You should report this on the meta site of the Stack Exchange site that's associated with the room in question. And be sure to link to the room, too.

Comment: @Gilles IOT is the site I see this on.